# Vue access object in data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm new to Vue and can't figure the following out. I have an app which connects to a JSON Api via a `usePage()`

`usePage()` let's me use "`page`" as an object which I can use and access inside the  tag.

Like:

```
<p>This product costs {{page.price}} Euros and is {{page.width}} wide and {{page.colour}}</p>
```

However, can I access this "`page`" object also in the `data()` or `methods:` ?

Like:

```
export default {
  components: {
    …
  },
  
  // Vue 3 setup
  setup () {
    return {
      page: usePage(),
    }
  },
  
  data: function() {
    return {
      product: {
        price: this.page.price,
        width: this.page.width,
        colour: this.page.colour
      }
    };
  }
}
```

It seems to return undefined. Is it not possible in Vue to access the same objects outside the `<template>` tag than inside the `<template>` tag?

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2):

You should not interchange properties between setup and other options like data, methods ..., in your case you could use a computed property instead of data option :

```
import {computed} from 'vue'

export default {
  components: {
    …
  },
  
  // Vue 3 setup
  setup () {

   const page = usePage();
   const product= computed(()=>({
        price: page.price,
        width: page.width,
        colour: page.colour
      }))
    return {
      page,product
    }
  },
  
 
}
```

Comment: Hi, thx, ok so I always need to use reactive() to access those "global" variables/objects?

Comment: Ok, so I tried your suggestion, however it says `product.price` for instance is `undefined` which means, it can't find `page.price` although I'm using it within the `<template>` tag. A simple string works though.